# Why does chromecast api fail to load in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromecast

I am trying to open build a chrome extension that as a controller for chromecast app. The app fails to load Chromecast API:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED chrome-extension://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js
```

In my index.html header:

```
<script src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js"></script>
```

I tried adding the gstatic in the manifest:

```
"permissions": [
        "www.gstatic.com/"
    ]
```

So no success. What am I doing wrong to include the API into the chrome extention?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extensions run on the scheme `chrome-extension://` not `https://`. Since you have a scheme agnostic URL in `<script/>` Chrome tries to load the resource from the extension files. Use `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/.."></script>`.

You will also have to change your permissions to include the `https://`.

Comment: To load scripts the source domain needs to be added to the CSP, not the `permissions` entry.